# How to Hide Dock Pannel Name I need the Dock pannel name on top but while Docking it shows in bottom also .. I have to hide it from bottom

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having 3 Dock pannels

Ex

```
                |pn1 O |  pn2 O | pn3 O|
```

pn1 pn2 pn3 are pannel names and  O - Icon for those pannels... I just want to show Icons not Images..Which property i can use for that...

I am having pannel text,name image at runtime i have to hide name and show only the icon..is there any property to hide name on runtime... 
in Dockpannel or in DockManager how to Hide Name of DockPannel Window while Docking it..?

I need the Dock pannel name on top but while Docking it shows in bottom also .. I have to hide it on bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(pathIcon1);
panel2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(pathIcon2);
panel3.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(pathIcon3);
```

Comment: ya @ Candie I am having pannel text,name image at runtime i have to hide name and show only the icon..

Comment: if you want erase your text , it's coorect and clean as solution to set  panel.Text = ""; you don't have this. here link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx

Comment: Candie i did that but in my code i need that text internally because at some places i am getting the dock pannel by its name..so i need it internally but have to hide from userview

Comment: So for your code you add label, you set text, and when you need, you set Visible="false";

Comment: I'am very happy to help you Aravind

Comment: I have another problem in this.when i made pannel.text ="" then top of the form name also come as null

Comment: you must add label in your panel with visible property in orde to isolate

Comment: How to do that can u send me some sample pls..,my mail is aravindsrinivas23@gmail.com